# How to prevent scroll when listening on the focus event?

Tags: javascript, scroll, focus, addeventlistener, event-listener

I would like to scroll to a specific element when focussing on an input text element but the focus causes unwanted, too much scrolling on mobile devices (this doesn't happen on desktop). If I focus on the input element via JS (see below), all works as expected but not when I focus on the element with the finger touch/mouse click.

So, I would like to listen on the focus event of an input text element and prevent scroll. How can I make that?

I tried this but it doesn't prevent scrolling:

```
inputTextElement.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  event.preventScroll = true;
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  // this causes too much scrolling on mobile devices (this doesn't happen on desktop)
  document.getElementById('another_element').scrollIntoView();
});
```

---

Even if it is not what I'm looking for but someway related to the case, I know that I can generally prevent scrolling when focussing via JS on an element like this:

```
element.focus({ preventScroll: true })
```

I would like to have something similar but when listening events.

Comment: I think you're out of luck. [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) and [`focusin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event) events are not cancelable, so if a focus event is dispatched then the browser's default scroll behaviour will occur. Can you elaborate on where these focus events are coming from? Preventing an input text element from scrolling into view is very similar to the behaviour of a keylogger so the browser tends not to optimize for such use cases.

Comment: @motto, the focus events are coming from a normal form with a click/touch on the input text field. On input field focus, I would like to scroll to a specific element (e.g. by using `document.getElementById('another_element').scrollIntoView();` within the listener) but the focus causes unwanted, too much scrolling on mobile devices (this doesn't happen on desktop). I updated the question.

Comment: You could prevent touch events on the input field by installing an element over the top, with a suitable click handler that invokes `focus({ preventScroll })` on your text input and scrolls to the other element. Might need to fiddle with `disabled`/`aria-disabled` to keep it working nicely with screenreaders and soft keyboards that allow for "tabbing" between elements.